# Кастомизация запросов в ROOM

Tags: java, android, sql, kotlin, room

Пытаюсь создать запрос, для получения конкретного элемента из дб с помощь Room.
Все запросы я отправляю с помощью аннотации Query к примеру:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM ${ExerciseEntity.TABLE_NAME} ORDER BY id DESC")
fun getAllCreatedExercise() : Single<List<ExerciseEntity>>
```

В данном случае я получаю все элементу из указанной таблицы, *но я хочу получить один конкретный элемент по указанному **id***. Id элемента указываю в edit text.
Но в запросах нужно использовать переменные типа **const**, получается, я не могу указать конкретный id в Query запросе.

**Как я могу редактировать запрос , что бы получить нужный мне элемент.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Передавайте параметры в запрос через аргументы метода:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM table_name where id = :variableName")
fun getDataById(variableName: Int) : Single<DataClass>
```